# Beautiful soup parsing crash from email html content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, encoding, imaplib

I'm triying to parse an email with html content with Beautiful Soup. The problem is when I want to catch for example a table included in an email.

Due to an encoding issue, I can't parse correctly and find elements by table, tr, td...

Email content:

- Table declaration

  ```
    <tab=\r\nle\r\nborder=3D\'0\' cellspacing=3D\'0\' cellpadding=3D\'5\' style=3D\'font-family: Aria=\r\nl;\r\nfont-size:13px;\'>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
  ```
- Column declaration

  <t=\r\nd> Buy

Theoretically, mail encoding is UTF-8:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Encoding in python is like this:

```
    for sent in msgs[0]:
    if type(sent) is tuple:
        # encoding set as utf-8
        content = str(sent[1], 'utf-8')
        data = str(content)
```

sent[1] is the mail content, and then I encode data to str in UTF-8 to use it in Beautiful Soup.

The question is, how can I fix mail content encoding? I tried to replace, ant others and It didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

***EDIT**:* If I resend me email, it works

**SOLUTION:**

```
content = quopri.decodestring(sent[1]).decode('latin-1')
```

Comment: Your email is also Content-Encoded with quoted-printable.  (check the content-Encoding header).  You need to undo that too, either using a MIME Parser, or undoing it yourself.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for your response. Researching about Content-Encoded I have found a solution with the following line in my Python script: content = quopri.decodestring(sent[1]).decode('latin-1'). Now it is working!